# Source for finding the right vocabulary

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, vocabulary

I have a clarification during my writing in expressing an activity. The sentence would be  "sea-shells and conches getting sedimented in that shore usually". I am unsure that the word sediment used sounds natural at this context.

I am also into similar situations in choosing words to the context. Is there a way / reference  to deal such issues?

Comment: I think a simple word such as *deposited* might be a better choice than *sedimented*.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd compose this sentence like this -

> The naturally occurring waves sediment the seashells and conchs on the shore

Note that *sediment* is used as a verb there -

> [sediment (v)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/SEDIMENT) - deposit/settle as sediment